# Porting a flash game to the iPhone

Tags: iphone, flash

I have a Flash game that I'd like to port over to the iPhone but I don't have the time nor the patience to do it myself, I also have a limited budget.

Can anyone recommend a place to put out a tender for an iPhone developer to port my game?

Answer (score 2):

You could wait for the [beta of Flash CS 5](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/), and use that to compile your Flash straight to iPhone....

Answer (score 0):

If your game has an existing community and content around it, try to partner with an experienced iPhone developer. They would port the game, you would provide the content and the community, and the revenue gets split. I am in the middle of this process with my online game (http://robozzle.com).

Alternatively, you could try to contract the job to a developer you found on a site like http://elance.com/ or http://rentacoder.com/. But, iPhone games aren't quick to develop, so you'll be looking to spend a considerable amount of money that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying one of the many freelancer sites out there such as http://www.ifreelance.com/
They tend to be able to hook you up with relatively low cost developers.  A google search for 'freelance software' will give you numerous good results.

Answer (score 0):

You can post job offers right here on SO: http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/
Furthermore, you could take a look at http://www.mobileorchard.com (free)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Game Salad](http://gamesalad.com/), a game construction kit. It looks similar to Flash game creation.